# How to block processing other messages in event loop during a CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1)
  }, 1)
})
```

```css
div {
  transition: all 2s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px
}
div:hover {
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">123</div>
```

What I want to do is to show a CSS animation first. And when that animation finished, run a javascript function `function() {console.log(1)}`. However, when I run this snippet, I found `function() {console.log(1)}` is executed before the animation ends.

Does this mean the CSS transition is independent to the message queue (event loop). Does anyone have ideas about how to block other processing messages in the message queue (event loop) until a CSS transition is finished?

I know that `transitionend` works if want to register a new callback, but what if there is already some callback registered by `setTimeout` in the message queue. I have no ideas about how to block them temporarily.

Comment: its timeout 1 milisecond, so  execute right away

Comment: @machun  If I write `setTimeout(function(){console.log(1)},1); while(1){}; `, `function(){console.log(1)}` will never run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event, but note that it will be fired when mouse is entered and when mouse is left

```js
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
  console.log(1)
})
```

```css
div {
  transition: all 2s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px
}
div:hover {
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">123</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  `transitionend` works well if want to register a new callback, but what if there is already some callback registered by `setTimeout` in the message queue. I have no ideas about how to block them temporarily.

Comment: sorry, I mean the event loop. When I use `setTimeout(callback, 1)`, as I understood, the callback is registered in the event loop..

Comment: setTimeout itself returns a value. You can call clearTimeout on this, provided that its scope is sufficiently elevated such that you can access it